# Python - How to find ideal solution based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Oddly specific one here, but here we go. I help manage a weekly event venue where we try to fill every single seat in certain rows. We have a list of regulars who we use to fill those seats, along with which seat or row each person prefers (if any). We also have some rows that are more important that others to fill - like if it's between having an empty seat in the front row vs having an empty seat in the second row, we would want the front row full. Of course not every single "regular" is available every single week.

Currently, we just manually place everyone as needed, but I would love to automate this as much as possible. I'm thinking once we've finalized our list of people who will attend the event for a given week, I would like to run the program and have it automatically put each person in the ideal spot, based on their preferences and ours.

A huge added bonus would be the ability to account for unexpected guests or no-shows. For example if someone RSVPs for two people, but they bring a third, it would be amazing if the program could then recalculate the best place to relocate their party (maybe even present different options with pros and cons. I.e "this solution moves the fewest number of people" or "this solution keeps the most important rows filled")

So far I've just manually plugged people in each week. This works, but is time-consuming, and is always a headache when someone brings an unexpected guest or has to cancel last-minute.

I realize this is probably a really specific use case, and I'm certainly not asking for anyone to write it for me. But to abstract a bit, is there a term for this kind of thinking/programming that I can look into? I'm trying to solve a seating problem, getting the best possible solution, while meeting as many "preference" conditions as possible.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: linear programming, maximizing a fit calculation value

Answer (score 0):

- Optimization = Finding the best solution out of many possible ones.
- Multi-objective = What is "best" is not determined by a single aspect but by multiple ones. Most often in optimization an objective function is used that gets a candidate solution as input and returns a numerical quality measure as output in order to determine what is a "good" and what is a "bad" solution. There are, however, also optimization algorithms that can deal with multiple quality measures as output and can try to find solutions that are good in each aspect, which may in your example represent the preferences of multiple people.
- Heuristic = An inexact method that can very often find a near-optimal solution in limited time. It stands in contrast to exact and approximate methods, which provide certain guarantees about how quickly they can find solutions or how near the optimal one they are, but such algorithms do not exist for every problem and it's sometimes not necessary to try to come up with one for a simple problem.

Suggestions for search phrases to get started: "multi-objective optimization", "heuristic optimization"

From the top of my head, I think an evolutionary algorithm using NSGA-II might fit these criteria and a Python library like DEAP should provide an implementation. The tricky part is probably writing a suitable objective function that captures the preferences of multiple people well.

Comment: That's good info, thank you! I'll read up on those terms.